# How to save selected check-box values into database dynamically using JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi i am new to JSF & Primefaces. I've been stuck for two days trying to persist dynamically selected check-values to DB.

I'm successfully displaying check-boxes using labels from DB using 3 tables:

- First table: DEM_checkbox which contains checkbox ID, label
- Second table: DEM_checkboxval which contains fileid, checkbox_id, value
- Third table: DEM_folder where all files save in table format in database

I've used separate mappers, services and classes for table.

This is my xhtml code:

```
<ui:repeat value="dossierBean.dossier.dui.demCheckBoxList" var="c">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="LeftColumn,LeftColumn">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{c.checkboxlabel}" styleClass="benefSelection" />
        <h:outputText value="#{c}" styleClass="subSectionTitle" />
    </h:panelGrid> 
</ui:repeat>
```

I'm using this loop to save selected values:

```
public List<DEMCheckBoxUI> getDemCheckBoxList() {
        if (demCheckBoxList==null){
            demCheckBoxList = new ArrayList<DEMCheckBoxUI>();
            for (DEMCheckboxes cblabel :dossier.getDemCheckBoxList()){
                DEMCheckBoxUI cbui = new DEMCheckBoxUI();
                cbui.setLabel(cblabel);
                List<String> valueList = services.getDemCheckboxValueService().getCheckboxValue(dossier.getId(), cblabel.getCheckboxlabel());
                DEMCheckboxesValue cbvalue = new DEMCheckboxesValue();
                cbvalue.setDossier(dossier.getId());
                cbvalue.setId(cblabel.getId());
                cbvalue.setValue(valueList.get(0));
                cbui.setCboxvalue(cbvalue);
                demCheckBoxList.add(cbui);
            }
        }    
        return demCheckBoxList;
    }
```

Labels are retrieved from DB via **DENCheckboxes.java**

Saved values are inserting via **DEMCheckboxesVal**

DemcheckboxUI is UI code looks like:

```
public class DEMCheckBoxUI {
    private DEMCheckboxes label;
    private DEMCheckboxesValue cboxvalue;
    public DEMCheckboxesValue getCboxvalue() {
        return cboxvalue;
    }
    public void setCboxvalue(DEMCheckboxesValue cboxvalue) {
        this.cboxvalue = cboxvalue;
    }
}
```

To save to database i am using the below code:

```
demCheckboxService = DossierManager.getCurrent().getDemCheckboxService();
        if (dossier != null) {
            dossier.setDemCheckBoxList(demCheckboxService.getCheckboxesList());
            if (PgzTools.notEmpty(dossier.getId())) {
                reloadDossier(dossier.getId());
            }
        }
```

I think there is a problem in the loop.
It would be help if anyone give suggestion or other method to fix.

Comment: where is code to save the list data to database?

Comment: Why is that code relevant if OP already can't collect the data for that in first place?